# How can I integrate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^\frac{-x^2}{\Delta x^2}dx$

Tags: integration

I have a problem to integrate the function: $$f(x)=e^\frac{-x^2}{\Delta x^2}$$ like this: $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^\frac{-x^2}{\Delta x^2}dx$$
because I don't know how to treat $\Delta x² = x_2 - x_1$.

Comment: Can you give the  definition of $\Delta x^2$? if it means the square of some constant called $\Delta x$, then consider the change of variables $y = x/\Delta x$ and google for Gaussian integral

Comment: I think is like a difference of x, like $\Delta t$ for the time on physics.

Comment: I thought about Gaussian Integral but I'm not sure I can do like this

Comment: I guessed as much, but it doesn't help to have physical intuition if you can't actually pin down the mathematical definition when it comes time to do computations

Comment: Sorry, I'm studying physics, so I have physical intuitions ahaha

Comment: I don't mean (and did not say) that's a bad thing. I was just trying to get you to focus on solving your problem, and right now, the physics doesn't help. What would help would be things you are sure of that can imply the result above. Can you add some [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) to the question? Otherwise, I think my interpretation is reasonable

Comment: $\Delta x$ seems to be just a constant (i.e. does not depend on $x$), so the Gaussian integral should work.

Comment: Thank you so much guys, so I will try this